# How to get the total COUNT in a GROUP BY query with SUM

Tags: sql

I have a query which returns the SUM of four fields from a single table:

```
SELECT 
            MPC.MedioPagoID,
            S.Descripcion,
            MPC.SucursalID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), fecha,120) fecha,
            Referencia,
            SUM(MontoVenta),
            SUM(MontoDevolucion),
            SUM(MontoComision),
            SUM(MontoAbono),
            mp.Descripcion AS DescripcionMedioPago
        FROM MedioPagoConciliacion MPC WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Sucursal S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.SucursalID = MPC.SucursalID
            INNER JOIN MedioPago MP WITH (NOLOCK) ON MP.MedioPagoID = 
            MPC.MedioPagoID
        GROUP BY 
            MPC.MedioPagoID,
            S.Descripcion,
            MPC.SucursalID,
            fecha,
            Referencia,
            mp.Descripcion
```

This first query returns 238 rows, now I need to get this same value from a second query with the same structure:

```
SELECT count(*) TOTAL
    FROM MedioPagoConciliacion MPC WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Sucursal S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.SucursalID = MPC.SucursalID
        INNER JOIN MedioPago MP WITH (NOLOCK) ON MP.MedioPagoID = 
    GROUP BY 
            MPC.MedioPagoID,
            S.Descripcion,
            MPC.SucursalID,
            fecha,
            Referencia,
            mp.Descripcion
```

The second query returns 238 results with different values, I need to get the single "238" from the second query as the TOTAL, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: can you post the results of second query as i am not clear what are you expecting?

Comment: What SQL is this?

Comment: @Eric this is SQL 2012

Comment: @JRG, I'm expecting a single value from the second query : "238", which is the number of rows.

Comment: git it, try solution i gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `GROUP BY` causing the issue, but why not leverage `@@ROWCOUNT`?

```
DECLARE @Rows int
SELECT 
        MPC.MedioPagoID,
        S.Descripcion,
        MPC.SucursalID,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), fecha,120) fecha,
        Referencia,
        SUM(MontoVenta),
        SUM(MontoDevolucion),
        SUM(MontoComision),
        SUM(MontoAbono),
        mp.Descripcion AS DescripcionMedioPago
    FROM MedioPagoConciliacion MPC WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Sucursal S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.SucursalID = MPC.SucursalID
        INNER JOIN MedioPago MP WITH (NOLOCK) ON MP.MedioPagoID = 
        MPC.MedioPagoID
    GROUP BY 
        MPC.MedioPagoID,
        S.Descripcion,
        MPC.SucursalID,
        fecha,
        Referencia,
        mp.Descripcion

SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT @Rows TOTAL
```

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of result I was expecting @Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `SQL Server`, try the query below.

```
SELECT 
    MPC.MedioPagoID,
    S.Descripcion,
    MPC.SucursalID,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), fecha,120) fecha,
    Referencia,
    SUM(MontoVenta),
    SUM(MontoDevolucion),
    SUM(MontoComision),
    SUM(MontoAbono),
    mp.Descripcion AS DescripcionMedioPago,
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS ROW_NUM
FROM MedioPagoConciliacion MPC WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Sucursal S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.SucursalID = MPC.SucursalID
    INNER JOIN MedioPago MP WITH (NOLOCK) ON MP.MedioPagoID = 
    MPC.MedioPagoID
GROUP BY 
    MPC.MedioPagoID,
    S.Descripcion,
    MPC.SucursalID,
    fecha,
    Referencia,
    mp.Descripcion
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your query, you can add a `outer` query to your `2nd` query to get total count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) TOTAL
        FROM MedioPagoConciliacion MPC WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Sucursal S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.SucursalID = MPC.SucursalID
            INNER JOIN MedioPago MP WITH (NOLOCK) ON MP.MedioPagoID = 
        GROUP BY 
                MPC.MedioPagoID,
                S.Descripcion,
                MPC.SucursalID,
                fecha,
                Referencia,
                mp.Descripcion
    )
```